# Is there a generic equivalent to ArrayIterator from Apache Commons Collections?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, guava, apache-commons-collection

[`ArrayIterator`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/ArrayIterator.html) is handy (although I don't need the `reset` functionality), but like the rest of the Commons Collections stuff, it doesn't use generics. I checked [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), but I didn't see a close equivalent. Did I miss it? Is there another library of similar reputation and quality as the first two that provides such a thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(array).iterator()`

`Arrays.asList(array).subList(start, end).iterator()`

These method calls are cheap -- they don't actually copy any data.  The `Arrays` class is in `java.util`, of course.

Comment: Related question: If I wanted to invoke `partition`-like logic on an array, you'd recommend `Lists.partition(Arrays.asList(myArray), mySize)` rather than `Iterators.partition(Iterators.forArray(myArray), mySize)`?

P.S. Thanks for the great library.

Comment: Oh hell yes, Lists.partition() is way better than the other partition methods.  It just returns sublist views without copying anything.